# what is the difference between "magically winked out" and monotonic?

Tags: c++

I found this in the [ppt](https://accu.org/conf-docs/PDFs_2017/John_Lakos_Slides.pdf) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1DpVR0tw0U). (Thanks for @doctorlove
) I am a little confused about he difference between "magically winked out" and monotonic. For example, if I have a `std::pmr::vector` and it use a monotonic memory resource. The compiler may optimize its destructor as doing nothing. (maybe the compiler don't optimize, but it can.) So, no matter we call the destructor directly or not, there is no time cost. Monotonic memory resource and "magically winked out" may be the same thing at sometimes. What's more, "magically winked out" violates RAII (I'm not sure is it undefined behavior?), so using monotonic memory resource is just a way of "magically winked out" without violating RAII.
[image]

Comment: "magically winked out" is the opposite of "Normal destruction". Not particularly connected to montonic allocation. If you *only* store objects without a real destructor, like ints, you can cheat by not destroying the elements and just deallocate the memory.

Comment: It looks to be an ACCU talk, and seems to be online: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1DpVR0tw0U

Comment: There is also the strategy for moderately short lived programs to not bother with deallocation and let the operating system's garbage collection deal with it once the process terminates.

Comment: Monotonic and magically winked out are orthogonal to one another.  One is a kind of allocator type, the other is a kind of destruction of allocated objects.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between normal deallocation and winking out is that the destructor isn't called when an object is winked out. This is achieved by allocating the object inside the allocator, rather than just using the allocator for the objects contents.
Consider `std::vector`, which uses an allocator to allocate space for its elements. The `vector` instance itself may be allocated anywhere we choose, including inside its own allocator. When the allocator goes out of scope, the `vector`'s
destructor isn't called automatically, which means that the destructors for the elements (and their elements) are also not called. For a large data structure this may save a significant amount of time, even if none of the destructors actually do anything useful.

The following example illustrates the difference by counting the calls to constructors and destructors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory_resource>

class CallCounter final
{
public:
    CallCounter()
    {
        ++constructor_calls;
    }

    ~CallCounter()
    {
        ++destructor_calls;
    }

    inline static size_t constructor_calls = 0;
    inline static size_t destructor_calls = 0;
};

auto printResults(std::string_view description)
{
    std::cout << description << ": " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\tConstructor calls: " << CallCounter::constructor_calls << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\tDestructor calls: " << CallCounter::destructor_calls << std::endl;
    CallCounter::constructor_calls = CallCounter::destructor_calls = 0;
}

auto normalDestruction()
{
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource memoryResource;
    std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator allocator{ &memoryResource };
    // Notice that the vector itself is allocated on the stack:
    auto vector = std::pmr::vector<CallCounter>{ 5000, allocator };
}

auto winkingOut()
{
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource memoryResource;
    std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator allocator{&memoryResource};
    // This time the vector is allocated inside the memory resource:
    auto& winkedOutVector = *allocator.new_object<std::pmr::vector<CallCounter>>(5000);
}

int main()
{
    normalDestruction();
    printResults("Normal destruction");
    winkingOut();
    printResults("Winking out");
}
```

Running the program gives the following output:

> ```
> Normal destruction:
>     Constructor calls: 5000
>     Destructor calls: 5000
> Winking out:
>     Constructor calls: 5000
>     Destructor calls: 0
> ```

Notice that the destructor is never called when the memory is winked out.

In principle, the example is not valid C++, since it uses undefined behavior. The reason is that `CallCounter`'s destructor has a side effect, which means it must be called. This issue is important to notice, because it's the reason that winking out is considered an advanced technique. It can be difficult to be certain that none of the destructors in a large object graph has side effects.